# Parar video cuando cierre el modal

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un modal en el que reproduzco un video cuando lo abro, con `autoplayer`. El problema es que cuando cierro el modal el video vuelve a reproducirse desde 0. Como puedo hacer que cuando cierre el modal el video se pare??

**El código**

```
<button type="button" class="btnVerpromocion video-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-src="video/cesar.mp4" data-target="#myModal" id="paraForm">
    <i class="fas fa-video"></i> VER PROMOCIÓN
</button>
```

**El modal**

```
  <!-- Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg corrigeModal21" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content modal-contentCorrige" style="background: inherit;">
            <div class="modal-body">
             <button type="button" class="close close2121" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
             </button>
              <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video"  allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
                </div>
               </div>
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
```

**El Javascript**

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
      // Gets the video src from the data-src on each button
      var $videoSrc;
      $('.video-btn').click(function() {
          $videoSrc = $(this).data( "src" );
      });
      //console.log($videoSrc);

      // when the modal is opened autoplay it
      $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

      // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. Youtube related video is like a box of chocolates... you never know what you're gonna get
      $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0" );
      })
      // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
      $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
          // a poor man's stop video
          $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc);
      })
      // document ready
      });
```

Comment: Existe el metodo pause() que te permite pausar un video, solo debes usarlo con tu elemento video donde quieras usarlo.

Comment: Porque usas un iframe??, iframe no creo que tenga un metodo pause, porque no usar el elemento Video de html5?

Comment: Hola gracias por vuestras respuesta, podeis poner un ejemplo practico de ello!?

Comment: Hola @BetaM o riven me podeis poner una respuesta con ejemplo, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Usas bootstrap?, prueba >

```js
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("#video").pause();
})
```

Comment: Quería recomendarte usar los nativos de JavaScript, pero me di cuenta que tienes código parecido al de boostrap entonces me imagine que solo querías pausar el video sin afectar el diseño y las animaciones.